# getent and ldapsearch results are inconsistent concerning the loginShell

Tags: ldap, pam, nss, pam-ldap

I have a test that creates a user in LDAP with /bin/bash and I then modify the ldap attributes to /bin/noshell but the results from getent and ldapsearch are inconsistent for the shell.
This user does not exists in /etc/passwd.

When I do a ‘getent check72 passwd’ I get:

```
check72:*:6072:6072:Johnny Appleseed:/home/check72:/bin/bash
```

But when I do a ldapsearch command I get:

```
# check72, people, wh.local
dn: uid=check72,ou=people,dc=wh,dc=local
uid: check72
cn: Johnny Appleseed
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9OWVHdTdPVHIwVE15ajNQNEphdG9GR1cwZnQxa2Ftb3k=
shadowLastChange: 15140
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
uidNumber: 6072
gidNumber: 6072
homeDirectory: /home/check72
loginShell: /bin/noshell

# check72, group, wh.local
dn: cn=check72,ou=group,dc=wh,dc=local
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
cn: check72
gidNumber: 6072
userPassword:: e0NSWVBUfXg=
```

I have restarted slapd and nscd, any clue? Thanks in advance.

My nsswitch.conf looks like this:

```
passwd:     files sss ldap
shadow:     files sss ldap
group:      files sss
```

Here are my packages installed related to nss

```
nss.x86_64              3.13.6-2.el6_3  @updates                                
nss-pam-ldapd.x86_64    0.7.5-15.el6_3.2
nss-softokn.x86_64      3.12.9-11.el6   @anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3
nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64
nss-sysinit.x86_64      3.13.6-2.el6_3  @updates                                
nss-tools.x86_64        3.13.6-2.el6_3  @updates                                
nss-util.x86_64         3.13.6-1.el6_3  @updates
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the `nscd` cache with `nscd -i passwd`?

Comment: It would be good to mention your [initial question](http://serverfault.com/q/486052/152073) to avoid duplication of effort. (@SvenW: yes, they did)

Comment: Your other question mentions that the problem seemed to temporarily clear up but was not permanently resolved by clearing the `nscd` cache. By any chance do you have multiple LDAP servers defined, and have you made sure that the data is sync between them?

Comment: I only have one single ldap server.

Comment: The other question was resolved, it was about not letting ldap accounts authenticate via ssh with a bogus shell, that has been fixed with nscd -i passwd.

Comment: This question is about inconsistencies between getent and the ldapsearch command.

Comment: I'm assuming there's a typo in your cut/paste where the result of ldapsearch has the attribute oginShell, rather than the attribute loginShell ? :) As tentatively, with a lack of a loginShell attribute nss/sss might fill in the blank for you with /bin/bash.

Comment: Yes, that is a typo from a copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

The `nss-pam-ldapd` package allows LDAP directory servers to be used as a primary source of name service information. When I would run 'getent passwd', I would only see the users from the `/etc/passwd` file. When I started the `/etc/init.d/nslcd` service and then issued the 'getent passwd' command, I then saw all LDAP users and system users and the shells were synced.

The service did not start when I installed the nss-pam-ldapd package, I manually started it, and now everything works like a charm.

Also the order of the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` was very important:

```
 passwd:     files ldap sss   
 shadow:     files ldap sss   
 group:      files sss
```